# what is the difference between DTO and javax.persistence.cache.retrieveMode BYPASS?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

According to hibernate documentation.

[DTOs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#sql-dto-query) returns non-managed entities and [assigning BYPASS to javax.persistence.cache.retrieveMode](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#caching-management) means cache will be ignored...

**QUESTION:** What is the difference?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ok, javax.persistence.cache.retrieveMode only works with cache level 2 so it can't be compared to DTOs which does not use cache at all

Comment: Nope "non managed entities" do not live in an L1 cache. They are not managed, so are not in any cache.

Answer (score 0):

**DTO** as [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) states, is:

> ... an object that carries data between processes

so DTO is not an entity and  so not managed in any case (well, not necessarily you *could* use entity class as a DTO) but a class that just holds data.

You can query data straight into DTOs if you only want to have the data - for example to pass somewhere. Again because DTO is not an entity it is not cached so the data comes directly from the database. Neither you can perform any JPA operations on it.

**CacheRetrieveMode.BYPASS** affects on how EntityManager uses its cache when fetching entities - so using **`find(..)`** methods. BYPASS will bypass searching from cache first and forces to load entity always from database.

So these two things are not comparable directly because they are totally different things. But the difference you are after I think is:

- **CacheRetrieveMode.BYPASS** forces EntityManager to bypass cache and load entity from database when using `find()`
- **DTO**s when directly instantiated with JPQL, NATIVE or some CriteriaQuery are not using EntityManagers methods like `find(..)` but those tailored queries that will not result into entities so never cached regardless what is set with **CacheRetrieveMode**

Comment: DTO is a non-manage entity according to hibernate documentation